# PHP mySQL query to return a reordered list and count occurences of field value even if absent

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I have a mysql db table which contains a datetime column and a category column. I want to create a SQL query to retrieve all the values present in the category column and count how many occurences of each category values grouped by month/year of the datetime column. If it is possible, I'd also like totals to be returned. A total for the number of all occurences in a month and a total of category counted.

**Note:** the category values cannot be hardcoded because they are set by the user and stored in another table.

DB table has following structure:

```
datetime    |  category

2009-01-05  |  fish
2009-01-06  |  fish
2009-01-06  |  potato
2009-01-16  |  fish
2009-02-08  |  pineapple
2009-02-15  |  potato
```

I wish returned result from query would be:

```
Month    |  fish  |  potato  |  pineapple   |  total

2009-01  |   3    |   1      |   0          |    4
2009-02  |   0    |   1      |   1          |    2

Total    |   3    |   2      |   1          |    6
```

I think (hope) it can be done in a single SQL query but I can't figure out how.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you collapse it into that format in your application code?

Comment: I already do that tadman, but I want to let the mysql server do the work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first say that I think this feels more like an issue to handle in your presentation logic (php code).  However, SQL can produce such a result.  You are trying to accomplish two different things.

First, you're looking for a `PIVOT` table.  MySQL does not support the `PIVOT` command, but you can simulate it with `MAX` and `CASE`.  This works well when you know the number of potential categories, but won't work in your case.

Next, you want to have row totals and then a final total row.  *Again, this is more appropriate to handle in the presentation layer.*

However, using `Dynamic SQL`, you can achieve both a `PIVOT` table and row totals.  Here is some sample code:

First build your PIVOT variable @sql:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'COUNT(IF(category = ''', category, ''',1,NULL)) AS ', category)
  ) INTO @sql
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      @rn:=IF(@prevMonthYear=CONCAT(YEAR(datetime),'-',MONTH(datetime)),@rn+1,1) rn,
      @prevMonthYear:=CONCAT(YEAR(datetime),'-',MONTH(datetime)) dt
    FROM yourtable JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0,@prevParent:=0) t
) t
;
```

Now build your Row Summary variable @totsql:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(', category, ') AS sum_', category)
  ) INTO @totsql
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      @rn:=IF(@prevMonthYear=CONCAT(YEAR(datetime),'-',MONTH(datetime)),@rn+1,1) rn,
      @prevMonthYear:=CONCAT(YEAR(datetime),'-',MONTH(datetime)) dt
    FROM yourtable JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0,@prevParent:=0) t
) t
;
```

Put it all together:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT dt,
                          ', @sql, ', COUNT(1) total
                  FROM (
                  SELECT *, 
                        @rn:=IF(@prevMonthYear=CONCAT(YEAR(datetime),''-'',MONTH(datetime)),@rn+1,1) rn,
                        @prevMonthYear:=CONCAT(YEAR(datetime),''-'',MONTH(datetime)) dt
                      FROM yourtable JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0,@prevParent:=0) t
                  ) t
                  GROUP BY dt

                  UNION 
                  SELECT ''Totals'',', @totsql, ', SUM(total)  
                  FROM (

                    SELECT dt,
                            ', @sql, ', COUNT(1) total
                    FROM (
                    SELECT *, 
                          @rn:=IF(@prevMonthYear=CONCAT(YEAR(datetime),''-'',MONTH(datetime)),@rn+1,1) rn,
                          @prevMonthYear:=CONCAT(YEAR(datetime),''-'',MONTH(datetime)) dt
                        FROM yourtable JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0,@prevParent:=0) t
                    ) t
                    GROUP BY dt

                  ) t2
                  ;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96541/2)

Results:

```
MONTH       FISH   POTATO   PINEAPPLE   TOTAL
2009-1      3      1        0           4
2009-2      0      1        1           2
Totals      3      2        1           6
```

Comment: Thanks sgeddes! That's an impressive query!
It works fine on SQL fiddle but not on the target system. Version of mysql is a bit old. It will need an update.

Comment: @GeeD -- np, hope this helps out.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple nested queries or you can use mysql loops in this case. Easiest thing would be to get all the data you need and process it using php.